# SQL sum for date range while showing all stock

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT     STOCK.NUMBER, SUM(ITEMS.QUANTO) AS USAGE, STOCK.DESC1, STOCK.UNITS, STOCK.LOW
FROM         ITEMS INNER JOIN
                      STOCK ON ITEMS.ITEM = STOCK.NUMBER
WHERE     (ITEMS.IT_SDATE BETWEEN '3/31/14' AND '4/5/14')
GROUP BY STOCK.NUMBER, STOCK.DESC1, STOCK.UNITS, STOCK.LOW
```

This query returns all of the items as well as the quantity shipped out this week. However it is not returning the Inventory of items not shipped this week. I need to keep the SUM of the quantity for only a specified time to see the product usage while returning all of the inventory items just showing a 0 for usage or null.

Comment: Don't really understand your question, but I'm thinking you're trying to say you want to see ALL stock regardless of whether the `ITEMS.IT_SDATE` is in that range?? If so, you might want to play with your join type...

Comment: `WHERE` actually filters out the result after the `JOIN`. Its not easy  to solve this until we see some sample data and expected resultset and also how its different from what you get.

Comment: @JohnBustos Yes that is what I am trying to do

Comment: @BhupeshC I have included 2 links to show the results I am getting. As you can see I only get 13 when filtering by date but the Usage is correct. I get all 17 Stock items when I remove the WHERE but the Usage shows all products since the db has been created. http://s746.photobucket.com/user/iceman1019/media/Capture2.jpg.html?sort=3&o=0    http://s746.photobucket.com/user/iceman1019/media/Capture.jpg.html?sort=3&o=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for all items from Stock, together with some values from Item, you should probably reverse the order of your JOIN condition and change it to an INNER (only items that match) to LEFT (all records from the first table along with whatever matches are found in the second), like so:

```
SELECT     STOCK.NUMBER, SUM(ITEMS.QUANTO) AS USAGE, STOCK.DESC1, STOCK.UNITS, STOCK.LOW
FROM
    STOCK 
     LEFT JOIN
    ITEMS ON 
        ITEMS.ITEM = STOCK.NUMBER AND 
        ITEMS.IT_SDATE BETWEEN '3/31/14' AND '4/5/14'
GROUP BY STOCK.NUMBER, STOCK.DESC1, STOCK.UNITS, STOCK.LOW
```

This will show you everything from the Stock table, but the SUM() of Items.Quanto will only pull data from the time period you specified. Having the date range in the JOIN condition means it will only evaluate when looking at what data to pull from the Items table, not when looking at what to pull from both tables together.